# Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function | Updating dropdowns based on Django model

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, ajax

I have a problem when trying to update my dropdown (`<select>` element) based on Django model triggered by another dropdown (let's call it A) change.

I followed this tutorial:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

When I change the dropdown A, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
```

Based on similar questions I made sure that I include this line before my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

and I'm **not** using the slim version of jquery.

Here is the part of my HTML code of my dropdown A and JS that is responsible for updating the second dropdown.

```
<select id="my-selection" dropdown-data-url="{% url 'ajax_get_data' %}">
   <option value="1">First Option</option>
   <option value="2">Second Option</option>
</select>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my-selection").change(function () {

        var url = $("#my-selection").attr("dropdown-data-url");  // get the url of the proper view
        var my_selection = $(this).val();                        // get the selected input from dropdown
        $.ajax({                       
        url: url,                    
        data: {
          'selection': my_selection                              // add selected option to the GET parameters
        },
        success: function (data) {   
          $("#second-dropdown-selection").html(data);  
        }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I will be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: You sure there isn't another jQuery.js loaded in another script tag that is slim version? That is a very common reason for this error

Comment: show full error .

Comment: @charlietfl I checked it, this is the only place I load jquery. Do you think slim version may be included indirectly with some other library?

Comment: Possible you have a bundler merging scripts into one file?

Comment: @charlietfl I don't use any bundler, however when I open console and debugger in my browser I do see two jquery versions: 3.6.0 which I specify and 3.2.1 slim, I can't find any reference to the slim version in my project tho

Comment: I'm not a django dev but perhaps there is some sort of *"include jQuery"* type command somewhere? And what is being included is the slim version. That is definitely the problem though

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you very much for your help so far, I'll try to dig and figure it out

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I had another jQuery version in my project (3.2.1 slim), however I didn't import it anywhere, probably some Django libraries had reference to it but I couldn't find it.

To solve this I used to point to my jQuery 3.6.0 (normal version).

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $360 = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

Then I use $360 in ajax instead of $ to point use this specific jQuery version.

Answer (score -1):

May be you missed the type (GET/POST) in the ajax call

```
$.ajax({                       
    url: url, 
    type:'get', //add this                  
    data: {
      'selection': my_selection 
    },
    success: function (data) {   
      $("#second-dropdown-selection").html(data);  
    }
    });
```

Comment: Would not cause error OP experienced as it defaults to GET